# Need Excel UDF to remove nonnumeric characters

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have a list of what classifies as a non-numeric.
Please help

Comment: You want it to ONLY remove characters 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have included that other UDF at all.

I need to remove non-numeric characters i.e keeping just 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

Answer (score 2):

Here are both routines, one to remove all numeric characters, and the other to remove everything but numeric characters:

```
Function deleteNumeric(strSource As String) As String
    Dim delChar As Integer
    For delChar = 48 To 57 ' ASCII code 48 is '0', through to 57 for '9'
        strSource = Replace(strSource, Chr(delChar), "")
    Next
    deleteNumeric = strSource
End Function

Function keepNumeric(strSource As String) As String
    Dim indxChar As Long, eachChar As String
    For indxChar = 1 To Len(strSource)
        eachChar = Asc(Mid(strSource, indxChar, 1))
        If eachChar > 47 And eachChar <= 57 Then
        keepNumeric = keepNumeric & Chr(eachChar)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Is it just me or is it hard to understand whether the op wants to keep numbers or get rid of them?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have included that other UDF at all. I've edited it out now the request should be clearer I need to remove non-numeric characters i.e keeping just 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

Answer (score 1):

One of these should do.

```
Function keepNums(str As String)
    Static rgx As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    keepNums = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        keepNums = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function

Function delNums(str As String)
    Static rgx As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    delNums = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]"
        delNums = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: With `.Replace`, if you want to return the original string if `.Pattern` is not present, you can omit the `If .Test(…` portion.  Just use `Result = .Replace(str, vbNullString)` by itself